# Jquery not working as I wish

Tags: jquery, css

I have this HTML code:

```
<div id="switcher" >
<h3>Style Switcher</h3>
<button id="switcher-large">
Large Print
</button>
    <br/> <br/>text
</div>
```

And this jquery code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#switcher-large').bind('click', function() {
$('#switcher').addClass('large');
});
});
```

And I have this CSS style

```
.large  {
font-size: 2.5em;
}**strong text**
```

I want the text inside the div to become 2.5em when I click the button but it´s not working as I wish.
Here its the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/MzJaH/

Comment: Your fiddle works fine once you include jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/MzJaH/8/. Also, `.bind()` was deprecated in favor of `.on()`.

Comment: it works as long as you'r using jquery http://jsfiddle.net/MzJaH/7/ you havn't included jquery in your original fiddle.

Comment: as soon as you change in your jsfiddle the framework from pure javascript to jquery all works as expected.

Comment: I am starting to learn jquery... thx for the help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is fine, remember to add jQuery to project in jsFiddle. On the left hand side, choose jQuery from the list of libs!

Answer (score 2):

You weren't including jQuery in your fiddle. I added jQuery from the menu at the top of the left sidebar. http://jsfiddle.net/MzJaH/11/

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#switcher-large').click(function() {
        $('#switcher').addClass('large');
    });
});
```

I also changed `.bind` click to `.click`.

Answer (score 0):

You should reference jQuery js first

Answer (score 0):

Better use`.click` You forgot about jQuery!
Here it is.
http://jsfiddle.net/MzJaH/13/